# Unit spacing in bibliography with siunitx

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texmaker, siunitx, units

I am using the `siunitx` package to manage unit spacing in my text, but I just realized that it is not working properly when used in the references (using `BibTex`). `TeXmaker` does not through any errors or warnings when compiling either the `.bib` or the `.tex`. Am I missing something?

Example:

```
...
title = "Far-infrared surface-plasmon quantum-cascade lasers at $\SI{21.5}{\mu m}$ and $\SI{24}{\mu m}$ wavelengths",
...
```

Comes out as:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a fully compilable example, then it is a lot easier to help.

Comment: That is not the correct way to use siunitx, does `\micro\metre` make a difference?

Comment: It works fine in the body of the document. I tried `\micro\metre` and got  4 errors `! Undefined control sequence.\micro` ...

Comment: You have to use it inside the second argument of `\SI{} {} ` of course.

Comment: That was what I did, got the control sequence error.

Comment: Then please do what I asked at the start a fully compilable minimal example (or at least so we can see what you are doing right now) , including preamble and sample bib file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! By providing a minimal example of code you increase the chances to receive a good answer, rather than generic advice.

Comment: BTW, does `{\SI{2.5}{\micro\metre}}` help, since it is inside a bibtex title.

Comment: Yes! That compiled just fine with the correct spacing. Thanks!

Comment: I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things here.

1. You should use `\micro\metre` not `\mu m`
2. Since bibtex styles may alter casing in titles it may be necessary to use `{\SI{2.5}{\micro\metre}}` to protect it.

The reason why you got an error, is that the title casing done by bibtex leaves you with `\si{2.5}{\micro\metre}` but the `\si` command only takes one argument, so the other bleeds into the main doc where `\micro` is not defined